# Sort list of different model objects by different fields

Tags: python, django

What is the most Pythonic way to sort on different fields a list that may contain two distinct types of Django model objects? Here's an example:

The models:

```
class A(models.Model):
        creation_time = models.DateTimeField()
class B(models.Model):
        last_updated = models.DateTimeField()
```

The view:

```
a = A.objects.all().order_by('creation_time')
b = B.objects.all().order_by('last_updated')
c = list(chain(a, b))
# Now I want to organize the contents of c by date pertaining to each object.
```

How can I sort with different keys on each object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort the list `c` in place using

```
c.sort(key=lambda x: getattr(x, 'creation_time', None) or getattr(x, 'creation_date', None))
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. My original code would result in a keyerror. And thanks to Dylan for the edit.